# How can I fetch all events from an organizer in Eventbrite using their API?

Tags: python, api, https, get, eventbrite

I have been trying to fetch all events from an organizer in Eventbrite for a while now, and I cannot get it to work.

For example, if we have [this organizer](https://www.eventbrite.com/o/devnetwork-2207661205), according to [Eventbrite's API](https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/reference/event/list/list-events-by-organization), to list all events from that organizer, we run a GET request from the following URL:

https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/organization_id/events/

Now, according to Eventbrite *organization_id* is a number, but they don't actually explain where to find the *organization_id* from an organizer's page. I read [this article](https://help.signaturesatori.com/en/articles/1002985-how-to-obtain-eventbrite-organizer-id) which explains that the *organization_id* is the number at the end of an organizer's URL. This theory makes sense, but when I try to run a GET request from the URL mentioned above, it still fails. I have tried using the organizer's full URL name (devnetwork-2207661205) and the number alone (2207661205), yet nothing works for me.

I've used Postman and Python to run my GET request, with no luck. My Python script looks like this:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/2207661205/events/'

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {{MY_PRIVATE_TOKEN}}'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).json()
print(json.dumps(response, indent=4))
```

I reveive the following HTTP response:

```
{
    "status_code": 404,
    "error_description": "The organization_id you requested does not exist.",
    "error": "NOT_FOUND"
}
```

Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the organisation is meant to be the ones you own, not others.

Comment: there's an organizations endpoint and an organizers endpoint that's separate

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the organizer filter:

'eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/***organizationid***/events/?status=live&***organizer_filter=organizerid***